# Error in Repast Simphony Project auto generation

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, repast-simphony

I have just installed Groovy and Repast Simphony in my Eclipse and created a Repast Simphony Project. In the auto-generated files is an error.
In the ModelInitializer class, the import:

```
import static repast.simphony.essentials.RepastEssentials.*
```

throws an error: Groovy:unable to resolve class repast.simphony.essentials.RepastEssentials

(I checked the filesystem and the file exists at the given location)

When I remove the static keyword, the error is gone, but the second error "Groovy:class ProbeID is not an annotation in @ProbeID" (this is the annotation at the toString()-method) is still there.

I'm running Eclipse on my Windows 7 machine, Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600
Java: 1.8.0_31

I have installed in eclipse (for Repast):

- Groovy Compiler 2.3 Feature (2.9.1.xx)
- JDT Core patch for Groovy-Eclipse plugin on Eclipse 4.4  (2.9.1.xx)
- Repast Simphony 2.3.1

Any ideas what might cause the problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that Repast Simphony doesn't run with Eclipse 4.4.2. You have to use Eclipse 4.2 when you want to use Repast Simphony.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you have installed repast Simphony and eclipse separately. Why don't you download directly the Repast Simphony package which comes with groovy compiler, eclipse and all?